# Very simple encryption API

Tags: php, security, cryptography, encryption

I need an encryption system with a super simple API. I'd prefer something as simple as the following. The output should also be browser-friendly and ideally url-friendly.

```
$encrypted=encrypt(data);
$decrypted=decrypt(encrypted);
```

I'm not a cryptographer, however I have come up with the following to achieve this.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

class EasyCrypt
{

    // format: easycryptstart_version_(bytes_of_b64bin)_b64bin_easycryptend
    // b64bin: base64urlencode(bin)
    // bin: versionspecific
    // V1 versionspecific: IV+aes128ctr(encryption_key=hkey,csum+inner_length+data+padding)
    // V1 hkey: substr(sha256(key),16); // sha256 is used as a key compressor/expander
    // V1 inner_length: little_endian_uint64(strlen(data))
    // V1 csum: substr(sha256(inner_length+data+padding),14)
    // V1 padding: null-bytes until strlen(csum+inner_length+data+padding) is divisible by 16 bytes (128 bits), (16-(size%16))%16
    // generate secure key: cat /dev/urandom | head --bytes=15 | base64
    private const EASY_ENCRYPTION_KEY = "CHANGEME";

    private const V1_IV_LENGTH = 16;

    private const V1_ENCRYPT_ALGO = 'aes-128-ctr';

    private const V1_HASH_ALGO = 'sha256';

    private const V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH = 14;

    public static function encryptEasy(string $data): string
    {
        return self::encrypt($data, self::EASY_ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    }

    public static function decryptEasy(string $data, string &$decryptionError = null): ?string
    {
        return self::decrypt($data, self::EASY_ENCRYPTION_KEY, $decryptionError);
    }

    public static function encrypt(string $data, string $encryption_key): string
    {
        $version = 1;
        $prefix = "easycryptstart_{$version}_";
        $postfix = "_easycryptend";
        $ret = self::encryptV1($data, $encryption_key);
        $ret = self::base64url_encode($ret);
        $ret = $prefix . strlen($ret) . "_" . $ret . $postfix;
        return $ret;
    }

    public static function decrypt(string $data, string $encryption_key, string &$decryptionError = null): ?string
    {
        // only 1 "version" exist thus far
        $version = 1;

        $data = str_replace(array(
            " ",
            "\r",
            "\n",
            "\t"
        ), "", $data);
        $prefix = "easycryptstart_{$version}_";
        $postfix = "_easycryptend";
        $prefixpos = strpos($data, $prefix);
        if (false === $prefixpos) {
            $decryptionError = "prefix not found";
            return null;
        }
        $postfixpos = strpos($data, $postfix, $prefixpos);
        if (false === $postfixpos) {
            $decryptionError = "postfix not found (even tho prefix was found!)";
            return null;
        }
        $data = substr($data, $prefixpos + strlen($prefix), $postfixpos - ($prefixpos + strlen($prefix)));
        $outer_length_end = strpos($data, "_");
        if (false === $outer_length_end) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupted input, outer length end missing!";
            return null;
        }
        $outer_length = substr($data, 0, $outer_length_end);
        $outer_length = filter_var($outer_length, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if (false === $outer_length) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupt input, outer_length non-int!";
            return null;
        }
        $data = substr($data, $outer_length_end + strlen("_"));
        $dlen = strlen($data);
        if ($dlen < $outer_length) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupt input, outer length header said {$outer_length} bytes, but only {$dlen} bytes available!";
            return null;
        }
        $data = substr($data, 0, $outer_length);
        $data = self::base64url_decode($data);
        return self::decryptV1($data, $encryption_key, $decryptionError);
    }

    private static function decryptV1(string $data, string $encryption_key, string &$decryptionError = null): ?string
    {
        if (strlen($data) < self::V1_IV_LENGTH) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupt input, IV is missing!";
            return null;
        }
        $IV = substr($data, 0, self::V1_IV_LENGTH);
        $data = substr($data, self::V1_IV_LENGTH);
        // now we have the aes128 data..
        if (strlen($data) < 16 || (strlen($data) % 16) !== 0) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupted input, after removing IV, data is not a multiple of 16 bytes!";
            return null;
        }
        $hkey = hash(self::V1_HASH_ALGO, $encryption_key, true);
        $hkey = substr($hkey, 0, 16);
        $data = openssl_decrypt($data, self::V1_ENCRYPT_ALGO, $hkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $IV);
        if (! is_string($data)) {
            // should never happen
            throw new \RuntimeException("openssl_decrypt failed! wtf!?");
        }
        if (strlen($data) < self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH) {
            $decryptionError = "corrupt input, after decryption, checksum hash is missing!";
            return null;
        }
        $checksum_supplied_hash = substr($data, 0, self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH);
        $data = substr($data, self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH);
        $checksum_calculated_hash = hash(self::V1_HASH_ALGO, $data, true);
        $checksum_calculated_hash = substr($checksum_calculated_hash, 0, self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH);
        if (! hash_equals($checksum_calculated_hash, $checksum_supplied_hash)) {
            $decryptionError = "checksum mismatch, possibly wrong decryption key?";
            return null;
        }
        $little_endian_uint64_length = 8;
        if (strlen($data) < $little_endian_uint64_length) {
            $decryptionError = "after decryption, inner_length header is missing!";
            return null;
        }
        $little_endian_uint64 = substr($data, 0, $little_endian_uint64_length);
        $little_endian_uint64 = self::from_little_uint64_t($little_endian_uint64);
        $data = substr($data, $little_endian_uint64_length);
        $dlen = strlen($data);
        if ($dlen < $little_endian_uint64) {
            $decryptionError = "inner_length header said {$little_endian_uint64} bytes, but only {$dlen} bytes remaining, and that includes any padding bytes!";
            return null;
        }
        $data = substr($data, 0, $little_endian_uint64);
        return $data;
    }

    private static function encryptV1(string $data, string $encryption_key): string
    {

        // compress/expand the key so we can accept any encryption key length (instead of the 16 bytes key required by aes-128)
        $hkey = hash(self::V1_HASH_ALGO, $encryption_key, true);
        $hkey = substr($hkey, 0, 16);

        $iv = random_bytes(self::V1_IV_LENGTH);
        $inner_length_bytes = self::to_little_uint64_t(strlen($data));
        $ret = $inner_length_bytes;
        $ret .= $data;
        $padding_length = self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH + strlen($ret);
        $padding_length = (16 - ($padding_length % 16)) % 16;
        $ret .= str_repeat("\x00", $padding_length);
        $csum = hash(self::V1_HASH_ALGO, $ret, true);
        $csum = substr($csum, 0, self::V1_HASH_TRUNCATE_LENGTH);
        $ret = $csum . $ret;
        $str = openssl_encrypt($ret, self::V1_ENCRYPT_ALGO, $hkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv);
        if (! is_string($str)) {
            // should never happen
            throw new \RuntimeException("openssl_encrypt failed! wtf!?");
        }
        $str = $iv . $str;
        return $str;
    }

    private static function to_uint8_t(int $i): string
    {
        return pack('C', $i);
    }

    private static function from_uint8_t(string $i): int
    {
        // ord($i) , i know.
        $arr = unpack("Cuint8_t", $i);
        return $arr['uint8_t'];
    }

    private static function to_little_uint64_t(int $i): string
    {
        return pack('P', $i);
    }

    private static function from_little_uint64_t(string $i): int
    {
        $arr = unpack('Puint64_t', $i);
        return $arr['uint64_t'];
    }

    private static function base64url_encode($data)
    {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

    private static function base64url_decode($data)
    {
        return base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$data = "Hello World!"; // . random_bytes(10*1024*1024);
$decryptionError = "";
$encrypted = EasyCrypt::encryptEasy($data);
$decrypted = EasyCrypt::decryptEasy($encrypted, $decryptionError);
$pretty = [
    "data to encrypt" => $data,
    "encrypted" => $encrypted,
    "decrypted successfully" => $decrypted === $data,
    "decryption error" => $decryptionError
];

var_export($pretty);
```

```
$ php EasyCrypt.php  | more
array (
  'data to encrypt' => 'Hello World!',
  'encrypted' => 'easycryptstart_1_86_LvBV6n3yLY-sH3vdhjzIZmbAm56s7VEZ9ah0wh5z4p9-rhJBaIDmOQYaWOTuRSei7yfmXJ6HTbqgvBaQJsQdMg_easycryptend',
  'decrypted successfully' => true,
  'decryption error' => '',
)
```

Comment: For a widely used, well studied secure implementation, [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox) is a good option. It is available built-in to PHP since version 7.2.

Comment: "I need a cryptography system! I'm not a cryptographer, but I'm going to make my own." This is basically the definition of a bad idea. Just use an existing crypto system, which *has* been designed by cryptographers and is actually secure.

Comment: @nick012000 you certainly have a point; but i'm also curious as to what mistakes i did, so having the implementation reviewed may be very educational for me

Answer (score 4):

Remove `encryptEasy` and `decryptEasy`; both functions are insecure and only serve to confuse possible users.

Your current scheme doesn't use a MAC, not a checksum which means the ciphertext is unauthenticated. [This is a bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44150/dont-use-encryption-without-message-authentication). It is recommended to use a HMAC function for authentication, in order to also avoid the risk of hash extension attacks while keeping the output range large.

[Encrypt-then-MAC is recommended](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac), while your current approach is hash-then-encrypt which is theoretically vulnerable to CTR bitflipping attacks.

Your padding implementation is incorrect if the data already contains null bytes (Use PKCS#7).

Instead of using a reference param for exceptions, just throw exceptions directly.

Comment: thanks for checking it! `order to also avoid the risk of hash extension attacks` - i don't think length extension attack is feasible on `sha256|112` even if the attacker had the encryption key? (for the same reason length extension isn't feasible on SHA2-384)  `theoretically vulnerable to CTR bitflipping attacks` - i would imagine any bitflips would break the sha256|112 hash ending up with `checksum mismatch, possibly wrong decryption key?` regardless of CTR vulnerabilities?

Comment: Nowadays you should use authenticated encryption instead of HMAC, if just because starting users are going to forget to e.g. MAC the IV as well.